# Roots of a trigonometric equation including logarithms

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

How would you solve this equation? Is it only possible to approximate the roots, if any?

$x\ln(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x) = 0$

My attempt: 
Treating $x\ln x$ as a constant - as it only has one root, which does not satisfy the equation.

Let $g(x) = x\ln x$.

Rewriting the equation using the double angle formula for sine:
$\sqrt{(g^2 +1)}\sin(x + \arctan(g)) = 0$

Im unsure how to proceed from here, and if whether treating $xlnx$ as a constant is possible.

Comment: You are **not** a new contributer. You should know that this question is going to get **closed** due to it's lack of effort.

Comment: My apologies, i have edited it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are looking for the $x_{(n)}$ which are the non-trivial zero's (there is an infinite number of them) of function$$f(x)=x\log(x)\cos(x) + \sin(x)$$

For "large" values of $n$, they will be closer and closer to $(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$ and, using Taylor series, we can make a first approximation
$$x_{(n)}=t_n+\frac{1}{t_n \log (t_n)} \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=(2n+1)\frac \pi 2$$ As shown below, this works quite well
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 2.980548660 &  2.127615825 \\
 1 & 4.849279237 &  4.842558340 \\
 2 & 7.915758772 &  7.914977694 \\
 3 & 11.03350795 &  11.03330637 \\
 4 & 14.16387161 &  14.16379619 \\
 5 & 17.29907017 &  17.29903524 \\
 6 & 20.43658637 &  20.43656780
\end{array}
\right)$$  For sure, for $n=0$, it is quita bad and, in any manner, we miss the first root which is close to $0.3522$.

This can be improved using one single iteration of Halley method. It would give
$$x_{(n)}=t_n+\frac{2 t_n \log (t_n)}{3+2 \log (t_n)+2 t_n^2 \log ^2(t_n)}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 1.859764165 &  2.127615825 \\
 1 & 4.841877979 &  4.842558340 \\
 2 & 7.914930457 &  7.914977694 \\
 3 & 11.03329639 &  11.03330637 \\
 4 & 14.16379284 &  14.16379619 \\
 5 & 17.29903379 &  17.29903524 \\
 6 & 20.43656707 &  20.43656780
\end{array}
\right)$$

Even better using a single iteration of Householder method
$$x_{(n)}=t_n+\frac{3t_n\Big[3+2 \log (t_n)+2 t_n^2 \log ^2(t_n)\Big]} {3+t^2 \log (t) \left(6 \log (t) \left(t^2 \log (t)+2\right)+17\right)}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 2.308913382 &  2.127615825 \\
 1 & 4.842590740 &  4.842558340 \\
 2 & 7.914978296 &  7.914977694 \\
 3 & 11.03330642 &  11.03330637 \\
 4 & 14.16379620 &  14.16379619 \\
 5 & 17.29903524 &  17.29903524 \\
 6 & 20.43656780 &  20.43656780
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

I cannot resist the pleasure of going further and write, as a better approximation

$$x_{(n)}=t_n+4 t_n \frac{3+a_1 t_n^2+a_2t_n^4 } {-4 +b_1 t_n^2+b_2t_n^4+b_3 t_n^6 }$$ where, using $\ell=\log(t_n)$,
$$a_1=17\ell +12 \ell^2\qquad \qquad  a_2=6 \ell^3$$

$$b_1=49+92\ell+24 \ell^2\qquad b_2=100 \ell^2+72\ell^3\qquad b_3=24 \ell^4$$ which, for $n=1$ gives $4.842556128$

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you come to your final approximation formula?

Comment: @formalT. I used the first iteration of a high order method (Newton is $2$ - I used $6$) and I still have much better !! Thanks for the problem. I had a lot of fun. Cheers :-)